# This program is just taking input from user but not showing output. Not getting out of while loop in main function

Tags: java, data-structures

I'm not getting out of the while loop in main method (while(!StdIn.isEmpty())
I tried all combinations to make a tree and I connected all the components still asking for input. I'm new to java and copypased this code from a book. I under stand most of it but not StdIn and StdOut library.

```
public class UF {
    private int[] id;
    private int count;
    
    public UF(int N) {
        count = N;
        id = new int[N];
        for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
            id[i]=i;
    }
    
    public int count() {
        return count;
    }
    
    public boolean connected(int p,int q) {
        return find(p)==find(q);
    }
    
    //find method
    public int find(int p) {
        while (p!=id[p]) p = id[p];
        return p;
    }
    
    //union method
    public void union(int p,int q) {
        int pRoot = find(p);
        int qRoot = find(q);
        if(pRoot == qRoot) return;
        id[pRoot] = qRoot;
            count--;
        }
    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        int N = StdIn.readInt();
        UF uf = new UF(N);
        while(!StdIn.isEmpty()) {
            
            int p = StdIn.readInt();
            int q = StdIn.readInt();
            if(uf.connected(p, q)) continue;
            uf.union(p, q);
            StdOut.println(p +" "+q);
        }
        StdOut.println(uf.count() + "components");

    }

}
```

Comment: I don't think `StdIn` can ever be empty. Don't know what that class/object is tho.

Comment: ```readInt()``` is a method from a ```DataInputStream``` I don't know your ```StdIn``` either, but it seems to me a custom wrapper class for such Stream. That would explain why it has an ```isEmpty()``` method. As Amongalen says, it seems that it can never be empty. So you would need to change your assertion. Easiest way to test would be converting the while-loop to a do-while, I guess

Answer (score 0):

I assume `StdIn` in some sort of wrapper around scanner, or at least, system input.

Assuming system input is not redirected in from a file, `IsEmpty()` just isn't a thing. Fundamentally never happening - most standard input streams are literally endless.

If you run your app like this:

`java -cp myclasspath com.foo.MyApp <somefile.txt`

then standard in can be 'empty' - that happens once somefile.txt's run out of stuff. But if you just run it as normal, like so:

`java -cp myclasspath com.foo.MyApp`

The environment's standard terminal input is hooked up as system in, which is generally your keyboard, which is endless, at least, until you press the 'end the stream' character, which is usually CTRL+C.

That's kind of a crappy interface.

A much nicer solution is to define an alternate command that can be input instead of normal input to signal that you're done. For example, decree that entering 0 for both p and q is the exit condition. Then:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        int N = StdIn.readInt();
        UF uf = new UF(N);
        while(true) {
            
            int p = StdIn.readInt();
            int q = StdIn.readInt();
            if (p == 0 && q == 0) break; // -- ADD THIS LINE --
            if(uf.connected(p, q)) continue;
            uf.union(p, q);
            StdOut.println(p +" "+q);
        }
        StdOut.println(uf.count() + "components");

    }
```

alternatively, perhaps the idea of that N you're reading right off the bat indicates how many p's and q's you want to read. In that case:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        int N = StdIn.readInt();
        UF uf = new UF(N);
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) { // -- THIS IS CHANGED --
            int p = StdIn.readInt();
            int q = StdIn.readInt();
            if(uf.connected(p, q)) continue;
            uf.union(p, q);
            StdOut.println(p +" "+q);
        }
        StdOut.println(uf.count() + "components");
    }
```